# In Iphone where to store large but temporary data like 1000 of images

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimage

My app is generating images from UIViews and this count of images can increase to great extent as the number of users get increased.

Currently I am storing these images in NSMutableArray, but when number of users are get increased my app get crashed with warning "Due to Memory Pressure".

I am storing these images in NSMutableArray because I need to generate a pdf of all these images.

I am thinking of writing these images in Phone directory, but I think it will also have some limitations and if no limitations will that be a best and last way to do this?

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store them as Files in the Cache Direcory of your App.

Get the directory with:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
  NSString *cacheDirectory = paths.firstObject;
```

Then load them if you need them.
just be aware of that the system can delete these files at any time.

To prevent them from beeing cleared up from the System you can use also the [NSTemporaryDirectory()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSTemporaryDirectory) and put them there.

Comment: system can delete these files at any time?? is it?

Comment: @Retro - The OP said "temporary data".  And I'm thinking the rule is that they won't be deleted while the app is active.

Comment: Yes Appledoc says: Put data cache files in the <Application_Home>/Library/Caches directory. Examples of files you should put in this directory include (but are not limited to) database cache files and downloadable content, such as that used by magazine, newspaper, and map apps. Your app should be able to gracefully handle situations where cached data is deleted by the system to free up disk space. - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Answer (score 1):

Initially, don't create images larger than you need. Scale them down to the smallest possible.

Secondly, don't keep the images in memory all the time, you don't need all of them all the time. Instead, save them to disk and keep only the path in your array so you can reload when required.

Third, when saving, choose an appropriate data type (probably JPEG rather than PNG) and compression factor.

Fourth, when generating the PDF make sure that the technique you use has only the current page in memory (saved pages are saved straight to disk). You may already be doing this but it's something to keep in mind just in case.

Comment: I have doubt here, will it take time to read and write images from and to disk respectively or is it negligible?

Comment: Yes, it will. But that time shouldn't affect you too much. And that's better than the app crashing... Indeed, my solution is the same as the accepted solution, I just added more info around the edges.

Answer (score 1):

Writing into Document directory is pretty good solution I guess because if you use `Coredata` then you have to convert your every image into data formate and save and then you have to reaload them and convert them which will make process less efficient.

On other hand you can save the images into document folder and in loop read then one by one write into pdf, so your memory consumption will be less!

Comment: I believe that Apple frowns upon storing documents in the Documents folder, although I'm not sure whether that will cause my app to be rejected

Comment: it will not i think, and you should delete the images after writing into pdf and do not make iOS busy, perform this operation in background  will solve most of the problem I guess

Comment: As the images will be used temporary you should prevent them from being synched to iCloud by setting the file attributes: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html if you active FileSharing via iTunes there are better alternatives than the Documents Folder (as you can see all the contents via iTunes then)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how large a single image is and how long you want to keep it in hold. Few points,

1. Get the images in right dimension from the server itself. Donot try to resize locally. 
   2a. Store the images into Cache directory if you are going to save/generate pdf immediately (ie., after few minutes in the current application life cycle).

   ```
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *cacheDirectory = paths.firstObject;
   ```

2b. Store the images into CoreData if the pdf generation is later, as in a different day.